# How to render the whole of image?

Tags: rendering

[image: http://oi42.tinypic.com/9awz8i.jpg]

How can I fix my problem?

my blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByScwSCTIaUGUVBzUTAzejdleDg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: While very informative, google has trouble indexing the text in your images. To make it search engine friendly, please don't embed the text part of your question in an image.

Comment: @Gunslinger Ok, I won't do this in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not do this in the compositor at all. You are giving yourself a lot of extra work.

The easiest solution is to place the camera at the correct place, giving you exactly the layout you want.

Like this:
[image: lock-camera-to-view]

The border around the render region turns red.

Open the options panel to the right (<kbd>N</kbd>). Use the normal view control keyboard commands to rotate and pan the camera until you are satisfied.